# How to ventilate a chimney taken down to attic (roof line) level?

Tags: attic, chimney, condensation

I had a leak in my chimney flashing, so the roofer recommended taking the chimney down to attic level. He repaired the roof where the chimney was (board, felt and roof tiles).

All was good, but a few days later I noticed there was condensation forming and dripping (back down the chimney) on the non-breathable felt just above the open chimney in the attic.

As a temp. workaround I stuffed the open chimney with some insulation roll and the condensation problem stopped. However, I've read that's not a good idea as eventually the roll will become saturated.

So options:

1. Close up the chimney in the attic with a (patio) slab?
2. Add tile vents to allow the condensation to escape?
3. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is this chimney still in use? Anything venting into it... Hot water heater, boiler, fireplace etc..?

Comment: I would be removing the chimney if nothing is venting up through as gunner is asking.  I did that on my current home gained enough for a nice sized cabinet.

Comment: Why is there felt in your attic?

Comment: @isherwood It's a 1960s UK bungalow. I think it was common to use non breathable felt then.

Comment: @Gunner No the chimney is not in use. There's a capped off gas fire at the bottom of the chimney, but it's purely decorative.

Comment: I guess I was confused about why the felt is exposed in the attic. Are there gaps in the decking?

Comment: I guess it was common practice in 1960s UK houses? It looks like this: https://job-prices.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/loftcondensation.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The insulation won't become saturated any more than the rest of the insulation in your attic will. If your ceiling has a vapor barrier in it, replicate that in your chimney by putting plastic on the inside of the insulation.

I had the same situation in a 1950s Minnesota home and it was never a problem after 15 years.